# How to block shiny app if a parameter is not passed in URL

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I want to write a shiny app. This shiny app will be used for analytics from other app (parent app).

My parent app has to call this shiny app. I want to make sure that my shiny app is invoked from this parent app alone. i.e. It should not be invoked directly using its URL.

For this, I am thinking of passing a key along with the URL of the shiny. In shiny app, I need to make a REST call which will validate the key. And this key will be valid if it is from my parent app. I need to block the execution of my shiny app if the key is not valid.

So as a first step I tried to check whether stopping/blocking shiny app if the parameter is not present.

I am able to read the http query parameters using [session$clientData](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html).

And I tried blocking using [validation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html)

Here is my server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$data <- reactive({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    validate(
      need(exists("query$foo"), "Please provide parameter 'foo'")
    )
    query
  })

  # Return the components of the URL in a string:
  output$urlText <- renderText({
    paste(sep = "",
      "protocol: ", session$clientData$url_protocol, "\n",
      "hostname: ", session$clientData$url_hostname, "\n",
      "pathname: ", session$clientData$url_pathname, "\n",
      "port: ",     session$clientData$url_port,     "\n",
      "search: ",   session$clientData$url_search,   "\n"
    )
  })

})
```

and here is my ui.R

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  h3("URL components"),
  verbatimTextOutput("urlText"),

  h3("Parsed query string"),
  verbatimTextOutput("data")
))
```

From the code, it is clear that if query parameter **foo** is not passed, "Please provide parameter 'foo'" will be displayed. But along with other details. I just want to display a page only with this warning. How can I do that?

As I am new to R and shiny app, I am not sure that my approach is right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` to show the rest of the app only when the query parameter is passed.

Here is an example:

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {          

  output$shiny_app <- renderUI({
    #check if foo was passed, if it is add the UI elements
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    validate(need(!is.null(query$foo), "Please provide parameter 'foo'"))
    plotOutput("plot")
  })

  #this output will only show if the plotOutput is passed by the previous function
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- rnorm(10)
    plot(x, y)
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(        
  uiOutput("shiny_app")
  )     
)
```

Comment: I will try this. But is my approach makes sense?

Comment: Yes I think it's fine, you just need the `validate` to block the whole app, you can either use the `validate` in each element of your app and they will all display the error message, or use it in a `renderUI` to "not show" any elements unless your condition is valid (I edited my answer to make it simpler).